# Dataframe apply method is not updating all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing the source and target dataset(9000 rows,14 columns) and highlighting the difference using below code. here using `apply` method i am calling the function.
but the problem is, highlighting difference works till some rows, after that rows are not getting highlight differences.
Not sure what is the limitation or am i missing something here?

**Note**: I am not sure how to attach the dataset file with this question but i am using sample csv with  9000 rows,14 columns from [here](https://extendsclass.com/csv-generator.html)

example here in first record, its highlighting the difference,
[image]

but after ID 4144, it not highlighting it.

[image]

below is my full code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def join_datasets(source, target):
    source_df = pd.read_csv(source)
    target_df = pd.read_csv(target)
    combined_df = pd.concat([source_df.set_index('id'), target_df.set_index('id')], 
                            axis='columns', keys=['Source', 'Target'])
    combined_df = combined_df.swaplevel(axis='columns')[source_df.columns[1:]]
    return combined_df

def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('Source', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

custom_style = [
    {
        'selector':'caption',
        'props':[('font-weight', 'bold'),('margin-bottom','25px'),('font-size','25px')]
    },
    {  
        'selector': '',
        'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse'),('margin', '100px auto')]
    },
    {  
        'selector': 'table',
        'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse'),('margin', '100px auto')]
    },
    {  
        'selector': 'tbody',
        'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA')]
    },
    {
        'selector': 'td',
        'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA'),('padding','1em'),('border-bottom','2px solid #A2DBFA')]
    },
    {
        'selector': 'th',
        'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA'),('padding','1em'),('background-color','#39A2DB'),('border-bottom','2px solid #A2DBFA')]
    }
]

df = join_datasets('source.csv', 'target.csv')
df = df.style.set_table_styles(custom_style, overwrite=True).set_caption("Test Case 1").apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
df
```

Comment: 1. reduce your dataframe to something small enough to pastebin as a csv, make sure the problem still persists. 2. Separate your issues: is this a jupyter error, or is your `highlight_diff` doing something weird? Can you add a column "highlighted" with True/False, to see if this is a rendering or data issue? 3. Don't use Jupyter as if it's excel.

Comment: @Ufos its not Jupyter issue and i am using pycharm as well and having the same problem. and if i reduce the record to 1000 ,it works fine. i think its somewhere the problem with apply(highlight_diff, axis=None) and this issue exist both in excel and csv

Comment: Unless you post your full dataset, no one is going to be able to know the reason. You say that the problem occurs with excel as well so its not a pandas/python problem. Maybe the problem is in the data itself or in the pc you are using.

Comment: @Mohammad can you let me know how do i attach my dataset file here?

Comment: @J_Coder you can for e.g upload the file to dropbox or google drive and attach a link here.

Comment: alternatively, if you would just cut your code down to the bare minimum, you might get some help (though including actual data is certainly highly recommended).  For example, you probably only need the function def and the apply.  all the style stuff you include just makes it a huge pain for anyone to look at.

Comment: FYI. `df_out.to_excel(...)` and `df_out.to_html(...)` work as expected. I see highlight cells til the end.

Comment: I've tested this in JupyterLab v. 3.0.16 and all 9000 cells get highlighted. I side with @Ufos on this one and suggest that you might have a rendering issue.

Comment: Instead of attaching a file you could also just fake the data. The error should happen regardless as long as the datatype matches. See [here](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) for more info.